# How to make reference to sqlite_master's field?

Tags: sql, sqlite

It's possible make reference to field `name` of `sqlite_master` table? Something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE metadata (
    id          INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    name        TEXT    REFERENCES sqlite_master (name) ON DELETE CASCADE
                        UNIQUE
                        NOT NULL,
    description TEXT
);
```

When I'm trying to execute this script then `SQLiteStudio` return error message `SQL logic error`. I need create table  with human-readable description of tables. I want make field `name` of service table `sqlite_master` as foreign key in my table.

Comment: Your code runs:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=0de4eb39cf923a4f7c148371946a6fbb.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @GordonLinoff No, it's syntactically corrected, but doesn't work with internal table `sqlite_master `, where listed all db tables.

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean?

Comment: @Shawn It's mean return error, when I trying run this sql script. Without `REFERENCES sqlite_master (name)` its work.

Comment: @Shawn script above, error `SQL logic error`.

Comment: Oh, wait... if you actually turn on foreign key support first, *then* it gives an error. Okay, that makes more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what's happening:

A column used as a parent key needs to either be the parent table's primary key, or have an unique index/constraint on it. The `sqlite_master` table has no such thing for the name column (And you can't add an index on it), thus it can't be used. I'm not sure why you're getting a logic error on table creation instead of a foreign key mismatch error at time of insert like you do in the same situation on normal tables, though:

```
sqlite> pragma foreign_keys = on;
sqlite> create table parent(id integer primary key, name text not null);
sqlite> insert into parent(name) values ('Bob');
sqlite> create table child(id integer primary key, name text references parent(name));
sqlite> insert into child(name) values ('Bob');
Error: foreign key mismatch - "child" referencing "parent"
sqlite> create unique index parent_idx_name on parent(name);
sqlite> insert into child(name) values ('Bob');
sqlite>
```

If foreign key enforcement is disabled like it is by default, what you're trying will be accepted, it just doesn't do anything and will raise errors if you turn on FKs later and try to do stuff with the table.

Comment: You also can't create triggers on `sqlite_master` events, so can't keep your table updated that way. I think you're out of luck.

Comment: thank you, now I figured it out. I will create `name TEXT` without foreign relation.